# How do you set scaling for a high dpi monitor and low dpi monitor independently? Dell 7567

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, scaling, hdpi

I have a problem scaling my 2 monitors. I have a Dell 7567 with a 4k display 3840x2160 and a external 34" monitor 2560x1080. the problem is that I cannot scale then separately. I have the 34" monitor as primary monitor and on this monitor everything works well but the 4k 15" display show all very small.

Info:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6400 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   2560x1080     59.94*+ 144.00   120.00    99.94    74.94    59.94    50.00  
   1920x1080    120.00   100.00    75.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    60.00    50.04  
   1600x900     120.00  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02  
   1280x720     120.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864     120.00  
   1024x768     119.99    75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
eDP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  48.02  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1024x768 (0x59) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x60) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x69) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

How can I set up both the monitors correctly?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Hi Sebastian,

i am running ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: According to https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/HiDpi you can get independant dpi scaling with wayland. Maybe you can try logging in using the wayland session ("Ubuntu", not "Ubuntu xorg" in case of 17.10)

Comment: Thanks sebatian. I dont not why but i can't do it :/